# VSCode extension API: autocomplete documentation/detail highlighting

Tags: vscode-extensions

There is closed [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/34188) that says the syntax highlighting is not enabled in autocomplete details.

Here is the code for autocomplete that has no highlight

```
vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('xml', {
        provideCompletionItems(document: vscode.TextDocument, position: vscode.Position, token: vscode.CancellationToken): Thenable<vscode.CompletionItem[]>
        {
            return new Promise<vscode.CompletionItem[]>((resolve, reject) =>
            {
                let ci = new vscode.CompletionItem("tag", vscode.CompletionItemKind.Snippet);
                ci.detail = "<Tag>detail</Tag>"
                ci.documentation = "<Tag>documentation</Tag>"
                ci.insertText = "<Tag></Tag>";
                resolve([ci]);
            });
        }
    }
);
```

And here is snippet code that provides nice highlight

```
"tag": {
    "prefix": "tag",
    "body": "<Tag>detail</Tag>",
    "description": "<Tag>description</Tag>"
}
```

So is there really no way to highlight the dynamic completion content like in snippet? looks strange...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to make your own styling.  Next week when v1.61 is due to be released you will be able to do this with the `documentation` value (`detail` styling is not supported):

```
const documentation = new vscode.MarkdownString(`<span style='color:#ff0;background-color:#000;'><Tag&gt;</span>
    documentation
    <span style='color:#ff0;background-color:#000;'></Tag&gt;</span>`);

documentation.supportHtml = true;  // new setting to be in v1.61

ci.documentation = documentation;

// I added this form if you want a tabstop at the $0
ci.insertText = new vscode.SnippetString("<Tag>$0</Tag>");
```

Note that because vscode, for security reasons sanitizes html in a MarkdownString, I simply replaced the closing `>`'s on the `<Tag>`'s with `&gt;`'s.

Also note that in the string literal, that tabs and newlines are currently stripped - so you can make your code a little more readable withou such long lines.

Demo:

[image: completion hover styling]

Comment: thank you, really looking forward to it